# i am getting this errors while trying to show my information through the API

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

[answer to C. Helling:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pV7Wp.png)This appears in the react web page

[image]

And this is my code in react

```
import axios from "axios";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [listOfPosts, setListOfPosts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("http://localhost:5000/api/regist").then((res) => {
      setListOfPosts(res.data);
    });
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {listOfPosts.map((value, key) => {
        return (
          <div className="post">
            <div className="title"> {value.email_U} </div>
            <div className="body">{value.nome_U}</div>
            <div className="footer">{value.pass}</div>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

 
export default App;
```

I try to put it into an array but still says that .map is is not a function

Comment: What is the value of `res.data`?

Comment: check your 'res.data', it's possible that it is returning an object instead of an array.

Comment: It looks like you have `res.data.data.` Try: setting: `setListOfPosts(res.data.data);` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check that `listOfPosts` is not empty before you call map on it.

Something like:

```
  {listOfPosts?.length > 0 ? listOfPosts.map((value, key) => {
    return (
      <div className="post">
        <div className="title"> {value.email_U} </div>
        <div className="body">{value.nome_U}</div>
        <div className="footer">{value.pass}</div>
      </div>
    );
  })
  : null}
```

Since people in the comments seem to disagree with this approach, here is a working [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/fancy-architecture-4ky8mf?file=/src/App.tsx). Except I replaced the return null with something that says ""Data loading..." and mocked an API request. Note that checking `listOfPosts?.length > 0` implicitly filters out if he's returning undefined or null or some other ill-defined response. But yes, he should probably log the output of his API call to check that the data is what he expects.

Comment: What's wrong with calling `.map()` on an empty array?

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros Empty array is fine, but `listOfPosts` is not defined when the page is initialized, and that's likely when it's throwing the error. I usually just check length out of habit, because you might want to show something else if there are no results.

Comment: Who are you answering, @Cristian? :)

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros both in a way

listOfPosts can be: 1) null or undefined, 2) not an array. So, make sure that: a) initialize listOfPosts like you did [], b) the api return an actual array and not null/undefined or other values.

Comment: @C.Helling, `listOfPosts` is initialised; check out the `useState` hook.

Comment: @Cristian but I'm not OP, I hope you noticed that :) I still think that this answer is incorrect though and your second point is the correct one.

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros ops! my bad :) i actually didn't

Comment: @C.Helling thank you my friend the error really disappeared, now I just need away to make the information appear in the page since the data is already getting inside the browser

Comment: @vortexe You should check what your webservice is returning. Maybe try adding to your useEffect something like `console.log(res)` or `console.log(JSON.stringify(res))`. We can't help you debug your locally hosted webservice but the issue is likely there.

Comment: @C.Helling i already checked and it's returning me the right thing, but it is not showing it on the page

Comment: @vortexe Are you sure it's returning an array of objects? Do you mind adding to the question exactly what it's outputting to javascript if you do the console.log() I recommended above? You can also try adding it to the code sandbox I linked in my answer.

Comment: @C.Helling I put  a foto in the my question above

Answer (score 0):

listOfPosts can be:

1. null or undefined
2. not an array

Make sure that:

1. initialize listOfPosts like you did useState([])
2. the api return an actual array and not null/undefined or other values (check res.data)